# Disable selection of specific items in a List

Tags: swiftui, swiftui-list

I have this simple list:

```
struct ContentView: View {
    
    let items = ["Item 1", "Item 2", "Item 3", "Item 4"]
    @State var selection: String? = nil
    
    var body: some View {
        
        List(selection: self.$selection) {
            ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
                Text(item)
                    .tag(item)
            }
        }
        
    }
}
```

Now I would like to disable the selection of specific list items, say for example "Item 2" and "Item 4". I cannot find a way to achieve this. Is it even possible?

**EDIT**

I already tried:

1. Using a `.onTapGesture` with just a `return` will not work, because you can click beside the text and it will still select.
2. Using again a `.onTapGesture` but with a `.contentShape(Rectangle()` will also not work.

Comment: have you tried with `.disabled` modifier?

Comment: Yes of course. But `.disabled` doesn't do anything on `Text()` and using a `Button()` doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I now solved it by creating the following modifier:

```
extension View {
    func tag<V>(_ tag: V, selectable: Bool) -> some View where V : Hashable {
        Group {
            if selectable == true {
                self.tag(tag)
            } else {
                self.foregroundColor(.secondary)
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then I can use

```
List(selection: self.$selection) {
    ForEach(self.items, id: \.self) { item in
        Text(item)
            .tag(item, selectable: self.isSelectable)
        }
    }
}
```

Just to mention it: This is necessary, a conditional `.tag` modifier like `.tag(self.isSelectable == true ? item : nil)` doesn't work.

Answer (score 1):

We now have the `.selectionDisabled()` modifier (available since iOS17+, macOS14+ etc).